# Split string and then remove prefix in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Google Sheet is populated with a string of the following format:

```
Monday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Tuesday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Wednesday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Thursday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Friday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Saturday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Sunday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM
```

My goal is to split the string into different columns and then remove the Prefix from each cell, something like:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM |

I used `=SPLIT(B2,",")` formula, but obviously it only split the string without remove the prefix.
How can I remove those, preferably before using the SPLIT formula?
I thought maybe use RegEx to remove all characters between and including "`,`" and "`:` ", except I don't know how. Note that filtering only numeric characters is not an option as in some cases property will be `"Closed"` instead of hours or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B2, ",", true), ":\s(.*)"))

Comment: your formula doesn't extract weekdays

Comment: Apparently, in some scenarios where the business has multiple opening ranges a day, the API generate extra outputs which the formula cannot handle (```Monday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Tuesday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Wednesday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Thursday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Friday: Closed,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 A```). How I figure it out? And how do I make the formula indicate the number of outputs and run accordingly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2iqH.png

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,",")),": ",FALSE)))
```

Comment: nice one, does the job

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is in cell `A1`, your formula would therefore be:

```
={arrayformula(substitute(regexextract(split(A1, ","),"[A-Z][a-z]+: "), ": ", "")); arrayformula(regexextract(split(A1, ","),"[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d +[AP]M – [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d +[AP]M"))}
```

It splits the string by comma, then extracts the week day  and the time and puts them in a matrix.

[image: formula demo]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Works like magic! By the end I plan to make an array formula out of it, so a repeating header after each row is not quite necessary, but I'll save this one!

Comment: from your task I understood you did want to extract the weekdays

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=transpose(split(substitute(substitute(substitute(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Monday[:0-9\–, APM]+"),", ","|"),": ","|"),",",""),"|"))
```

then replace Monday by Tuesday, Wednesday etc.
[image]