# Split string and then remove prefix in Google Sheets (Again)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

my Google Sheet is populated with different string of the following format:

```
Monday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Tuesday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Wednesday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Thursday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Friday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Saturday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Sunday: 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM
```

My goal was to split the string into different columns and then remove the Prefix from each cell, to create something like this:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM | 12:00 PM – 12:00 AM |

I used the formula `=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B2, ",", true), ":\s(.*)"))`  , as suggested by [Goran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431502/goran) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68791615/split-string-and-then-remove-prefix-in-google-sheets) and it worked perfectly fine, until I got strings with multiple time ranges a day like this one:

```
Monday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Tuesday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Wednesday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Thursday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM,Friday: Closed,Saturday: Closed,Sunday: 12:00 – 4:00 PM, 6:00 PM – 12:00 AM
```

Now the formula doesn't know how to handle this scenario, how do I fix it and make my formula act accordingly? Please help!

[image]

**Update:**
I'm not sure if I succeed, seems like it's working but I'm sharing a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C3fT2_B_tyoM6OCw7u8VJo6kpXZ-rD3tcbuXeb4jhHE/edit?usp=sharing) for you to still take a look!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, assuming that every string contains at least something for each of the seven named days of the week:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(","&B2,"[^,]*day:\s*","~"),",~",0,1),",\s*",CHAR(10)))`

If you will be needing to apply this to multiple raw strings in B2:B, just be sure that the output range (say, C2:I) is clear first and then use this version of the formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(","&B2:B,"[^,]*day:\s*","~"),",~",0,1),",\s*",CHAR(10))))`

**ADDENDUM** (after reading comment about Hebrew inclusions):

See if this works with the Hebrew:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(","&B2:B,",[^,]+:\s","~"),"~",0,1),",\s*",CHAR(10))))`

If not, do share a link to a copy of the sheet, per my additional comment below.

**ADDENDUM #2** (after further comments)

It is beyond the scope of any free forum to control for every variable. That would go beyond sharing information or giving a push in the right direction to what I would call "real work" (i.e., customized, time-intensive, expert services). However, I'll provide one additional formula variation to cover your latest update:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A10="",,SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(","&A3:A10,",[^,]+:\s","~"),"(\d)(\d\d)(\D)","$1:$2$3"),"(:\d\d)","$1*"),"~",0,1),",\s*",", "),"*","")))`

Comment: Works great in English, I guess the formula assuming all titles end with "day:"? My document is originally in Hebrew, where the way we say day names is quite different, we have a fixed prefix, the Hebrew word for the word "day", and then the name for that day. Something like "Day One:", "Day Two:", "Day Three:", anyway to still make it work?

Comment: Keep in mind that we only know what you tell us and show us. For that reason, it is always best to share as much as possible about the details of your real sheet. That said, I will ask that you share a copy of your sheet with the link permission (set at the time you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Edit." This will be the most efficient and effective way for my or anyone else to get all the details in order to help you. Please indicate at that time, if it is not already 100% clear, whether the strings read left-to-right or right-to-left.

Comment: See my addendum and additional formula in the post. If that works, problem solved. If not, do share a link.

Comment: Hey, I think the problem is solved, but I'm sharing a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C3fT2_B_tyoM6OCw7u8VJo6kpXZ-rD3tcbuXeb4jhHE/edit?usp=sharing) anyway so you can tell me what you think. Thank you very much Erik!

Comment: From what data you have in your sheet, it appears to be working (i.e., producing the same output as your "Desired Result" section). Unless future strings vary from the raw format shown currently in your sheet, you should be all set. Once you can delete your "Desired Result" section, I suggest you change your `A3:A10` references in the current formula version to cover the entire column: `A3:A`. Just be sure that the entire output range (`B2:H`) is clear first.

Comment: I've tested it again for various of strings. Seems like the only type of input which produce ```#VALUE!``` is when the value is an hour but not range ("12:00") or just a number ("1200"), as you can see in the sheet. This is the only gap I found. I rely on API to get those strings, as you probably guessing, so I don't really know what to expect.

Comment: See "ADDENDUM #2" and your sheet for an updated formula. Understand that the forum is now sending alerts that essentially warn that "too much is going on for one post." I trust this final iteration will serve your purposes. If not, I encourage you to submit another unique post where you fine-tune an additional request for the community. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the same question as beforwards [Import JSON into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784198/import-json-into-google-sheets#68784198) , but I have prepared an answer ...

```
function timeTable(url,e) {
  if (url.match(/http(s)?:\/\/?/g)){var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())}
  else{var data = JSON.parse(url)}
  var result=[]
  for (var i=0;i<=6;i++){
    result[6-data.result.opening_hours.periods[i][e].day]=data.result.opening_hours.periods[i][e].time
  }
  return [result]
}
```

with e = open or close / take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvs89rcG6HkPKXXsCmNUOjy5sCQxaJMSHobQLzS-vHY/copy

Comment: I will now have a look at this regex question.

Answer (score 1):

A solution, but has probably to be improved ...

```
=transpose(split(substitute(substitute(substitute(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Monday[:0-9\–, APM]+"),", ","|"),": ","|"),",",""),"|"))
```

then replace Monday by Tuesday, Wednesday etc.
[image]